# How to fix java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class Android

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this problem after replacing a **.aar** library with updated .aar.

**Logcat**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: bolts/AggregateException.class

this is my gradle code.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "--Package-- Name--"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.5"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':cometchat-sdk')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.2.9'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.eneim:Toro:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: the problem is bolts-tasks. It is being included twice somehow. Is there a jar of bolts in your libs dir or the cometchat-sdk? If you have a jar, remove it. else, try building with `compile (project(':cometchat-sdk')){ exclude module: 'bolts-tasks' }` Also, You can try printing out the dependency tree using `./gradlew app:dependencies` (replace app with module name) and see if you find two instances of bolts being included.

Comment: yes cometchat required bolts-tasks so i added it in my gradle. I think facebook also user bolts task so some how they are conflicting each other.

Comment: Facebook does declare a dependency on bolts-android:1.4.0 which i assume is a superset of bolts-tasks and bolts-applinks. Try removing the explicit bolts-tasks dependency.

Comment: but if i will remove bolts-tasks then cometchat will create problem. Okay! let me try it.

Comment: Other possible solution would be to exclude bolts-tasks from facebook dependency. `compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0') { exclude module: 'bolts-tasks'}` and keep the explicit one.